# how to use IAsyncEnumerable with EF.CompileAsyncQuery

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, c#-8.0

my code :

```
private static readonly Func<BSDbContext, Expression<Func<Salon, bool>>, IAsyncEnumerable<Salon>> GetSalonsAsync =
EF.CompileAsyncQuery((BSDbContext context, Expression <Func<Salon, bool>> predicate) =>
  context.Salons.Where(predicate));

 public async IAsyncEnumerable<Salon> GetSalons(Expression<Func<Salon, bool>> predicate)
 {
     return await GetSalonsAsync(db, predicate); //error line
 }
```

I am facing this error while using it

```
Cannot return a value from an iterator. Use the yield return statement to return a value, or yield break to end the iteration.
```

and

```
  'IAsyncEnumerable<Salon>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncEnumerable<Salon>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Do you try  `yield return await GetSalonsAsync(db, predicate);`?

Comment: yes..but get this error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<BeautySalon.Models.Salon>' to 'BeautySalon.Models.Salon'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Could you share your GetSalonsAsync ?

Comment: first line of code `private static readonly Func<BSDbContext, Expression<Func<Salon, bool>>, IAsyncEnumerable<Salon>> GetSalonsAsync =
EF.CompileAsyncQuery((BSDbContext context, Expression <Func<Salon, bool>> predicate) =>
  context.Salons.Where(predicate));`

Comment: Ok, how about `yield return (Salon) GetSalonsAsync(db, predicate);`?